# How do I trigger onchange from a default SharePoint 2010 date field?

Tags: 2010, jquery, events

I am currently running a function on change when a user changes the value of a choice field. This function uses the date (previously selected) to filter items for another drop-down list. However, in the event that a user has already selected "Yes" from the choice field and wishes to change the date, I would also like to trigger that filtering function when the date is changed on the default SharePoint date field.

I can get it to work if the user manually types in the date box and clicks off of it: (this is sitting in document ready)

```
            $('#specificDateFieldID').on('change', function(){              
               var date = this.value;
               queryEvents(date);        
            });
```

Does anyone know how to trigger this event listener when a user clicks the little calendar icon and changes the date there instead of just typing in the box manually?

I can post more code if this is not enough.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This was bugging me for days. The cursor is added to the field every time you select a date. Listen on the input field date picker prints your date to using "focus".

```
    $("[title='Date Received']").on("focus", function(event){
        var daterecieved = $(event.target).val();
        console.log(daterecieved)
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. I have successfully used the the `onvaluesetfrompicker` function of a Date field, like so:

```
$('#specificDateFieldID').get(0).onvaluesetfrompicker = DatePickerChanged;

function DatePickerChanged() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

But this was in SharePoint 2013. It seems from [this](https://theway4ward.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/211/) that it should also work in SharePoint 2010 with *custom* forms, but not in a Calendar form.

Comment: This is very close... it works great for an already existing value and it runs my function based on that pre-existing value (this is a custom edit form). However, it doesn't trigger if I change the date. I'll start reading through that article you linked to see if there's anything in there I can use unless you have any ideas!

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't trigger if you change the date manually by typing in the input box? In this case you could either make the input field readonly, therefore forcing the user to pick the date via the date picker, or you could set up an additional event as in your original post, pointing it also to the 'DatePickerChanged' function.

Comment: It doesn't trigger at all, with typing in text or using the date picker. The only time it triggers is when the document loads with a date already in the field. On change works for the text box itself, already.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't inadvertently done this: `$('#specificDateFieldID').get(0).onvaluesetfrompicker = DatePickerChanged()`? Notice the parentheses at the end.

Comment: I did put the parentheses at the end by mistake. I just removed them and tried again, and now I get an "unrecognized expression" error.

Comment: You'll need to debug your JavaScript. It sounds like once you can get your JavaScript working, my suggested solution will meet your requirement.

Comment: I certainly hope so! I will keep at it and let you know, but I don't hold out a lot of hope with my debugging abilities. :)

Comment: If you share the code where you set up the event and the corresponding code that runs on event firing I'll try and help.

Comment: Alright so I have this sitting in document ready: 
`$('#ctl00$m$g_12922bf0_eb5b_44d9_bfd3_054599098f16$ff31$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeField$DateTimeFieldDate').get(0).onvaluesetfrompicker = DatePickerChanged;`

I have this after document ready:
 `function DatePickerChanged() {
   queryEvents(date);
 }`

The date picker itself should trigger it (that's my intent, anyway). 

I am using jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: Try putting `alert("hi");` before `queryEvents(date)` to be sure the event is not firing. Also ensure when you make changes to JavaScript files that you refresh the browser page with Ctrl+F5 to get around your browser caching the JavaScript.

Comment: Definitely not firing :/ I'm wondering if I am simply grabbing the wrong ID from the form.

Comment: It doesn't look quite correct. The field id should be in the format 'InternalFieldName_FieldGUID_$FieldType'. E.g. `StartDate_64cd368d-2f95-4bfc-a1f9-8d4324ecb007_$DateTimeFieldDate`.

Comment: You could also try getting the field in jQuery like this `$("input[id='ctl00$m$g_12922bf0_eb5b_44d9_bfd3_054599098f16$ff31$ctl00$ctl00$DateTimeFie‌​ld$DateTimeFieldDate']")`

Comment: I have multiple DatePickers on my Page and I want to get triggered date picker object. like `$(this)` in JQuery. Can you tell me, how could it be possible with this method?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do this. The reason being when you click the calendar icon. It open the calendar control in an IFRAME.

It is not possible to attach any event to elements inside the iframe. And thus we can't capture date click event.

When we click on a date, there is a JavaScript running behind the scene which will update the INPUT control. Hence your `onchange` event is not getting fired.

I believe your only option is to use a timer along with the calendar button click and monitor the values in the `input` box.